# Google Sheet Query: Return All Row Data only in Distinct Columns

Tags: google-sheets, unique, distinct

I currently have a query returning all data where Particular columns match certain conditions, but I would also like to prevent the return of duplicate data from column1.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | y | z |
| 1 | x | z | x |
| 2 | r | z | w |
| 3 | q | y | z |
| 4 | q | t | q |
| 4 | q | u | r |

So far:
=QUERY(A:D, "SELECT * WHERE B = 'x' OR 'q'")

Returns:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | y | z |
| 1 | x | z | x |
| 3 | q | y | z |
| 4 | q | t | q |
| 4 | q | u | r |

How can I also remove the duplciates in column A? So it displays the below:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | y | z |
| 3 | q | y | z |
| 4 | q | t | q |

Comment: What is the logic for resolving/choosing the duplicate rows?

Comment: There isn't any - It can be the first row or the last, there is no preference which row is chosen as the relevant data is duplicated throughout the other columns.

Comment: Have you read about UNIQUE ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to go about this. Given your exact post information, which runs A:D with no headers, here is one way:

`=ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FILTER(A:A,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B:B,"q|x"))),A:D,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(A:D)),FALSE))))`

`FILTER` forms a limited array of only those items in A:A where the corresponding value in B:B exists within the `SEARCH` criteria string.

`VLOOKUP` looks up and returns all four columns of values for each of those, which will return the first row of values encountered for every equal value in the `FILTER`ed A:A values. This will result in exact duplicate information for each matching row.

I used `SEQUENCE` to return an array asking for the return of columns 1,2,3,4 from the requested range. This parameter could have been entered as `{1,2,3,4}`. But I find `SEQUENCE` to be more flexible, for instance if in your actual sheet you want the return of 12 columns and not only 4.

`UNIQUE` eliminates the duplicates.

And, of course, `ArrayFormula` is necessary because we are processing a range of values.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORTN(QUERY({A:D, A:A&B:B}, 
 "where Col2 matches 'x|q'"), 9^9, 2, 5, 1), 9^9, 4)
```

[image]